# Is there a way to turn on Twig syntax colors on the Beta site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, twig

I only ask be cause my SE app on my phone colorizes Twig syntax nicely, and I think that it would probably be a good idea to turn it on the main website if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

For now, I've enabled this for [twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twig), [template](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/template) and [php](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php). It can be expanded to more tags if need-be, or even enabled for all tags by default.

Note that you can trigger highlighting for any code block regardless of tag by using the [formatting hints](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Thanks! I already noticed ))

Comment: Thanks for turning this on. In case it helps anyone, the snippet to use to trigger Twig syntax highlighting on a code block is `<!-- language: lang-twig -->`

Comment: I lean toward enabling globally by default, though.

Comment: If you think it should be enabled globally, propose a separate feature-request, @Alex - there are some sanity-checks y'all will want to perform first, most notably making sure that this isn't going to screw up existing posts or catch new users unaware.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9. I actually don't anymore having seen the Twig formatting applied to some non-twig code. Probably best to be triggered manually.

Comment: Hi @Shog9... There has been some confusion regarding the Twig syntax highlighting on the Craft SE site. I've been investigating this thoroughly, and it doesn't look like [Google Code Prettify](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) supports Twig... Can you please clarify how (or if) you were able to specify Twig syntax highlighting for "twig" tags?

Comment: @AlexKendrick, you give an example of specifying Twig for a code block (`lang-twig`)... Did you see that referenced somewhere specifically, or did you infer it from the general markup structure?

Comment: If memory serves, I inferred it from this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @AlexKendrick Ah ok, that's what I suspected... I've done some research, and I don't think that Twig syntax highlighting is a real thing. I've detailed my findings [here...](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/78/twig-syntax-highlighting-is-a-myth)