# Bug in syntax highlighting

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

[Shog9](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/shog9) [enabled](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14/250) syntax highlighting some time ago. Wonderful. But seems like it highlights comments wrongly - as if they start with `#`:

```twig
{% if 1==1 %}
    {# do something #}
{% elseif %}
    {# something wrong with logic #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Twig syntax highlighting is apparently a myth.

I did a lot of research, and [wrote about my findings here...](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/twig-syntax-highlighting-is-a-myth)

Comment: Fully agree with you.