# Temporary removal of twig syntax highlighting?

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

Twig syntax highlighting in code blocks is a mess. Many things just don't work (see first [bug report](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/bug-in-syntax-highlighting) and examples below) and make reading code less clear than without highlights.

Please remove the feature until this works better.

.

**Problems**

Twig:

- Some Twig tags and operators are highlighted (1) and some are not (2)
- Filters are not highlighted at all (3)
- String "var" highlighted as twig tag (4)

Twig Comments:

- No highlighting of comment text and opening tag (5)
- Twig code highlighting not disabled within comments (6)

HTML:

- Different opening/closing tag highlights (7)
- Opening tag highlighted differently if attributes added (8)
- Twig code highlighting not disabled within comments (9)
- HTML code highlighted treated similar to twig code and vars (10)
- No highlighting of HTML comments (11)
- Complete twig syntax highlighting fails if the code begins with html ([see ex. here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1489/125))

Other:

- Strange highlights of words like "Twig" and "Comment" (12)

.

**Examples**

Syntax language set to `lang-twig`:

```twig
{% set foo = true %} [1]

{% extends "foo.html" %} [1]

{% spaceless %} ... {% endspaceless %} [2]

{% macro foo() %} ... {% endmacro %} [2]

{{ foo|raw ~ foo|length ~ foo|date('Y') ~ '...' }} [3]

{% if var == true and foo == 'string' %} ... {% elseif foo %} ... {% endif %} [2, 4]

{# Twig code within comments: extends, in, ... #} [5, 6, 12]

<p>Twig code within html: with, set, ...</p> [7, 9, 10, 12]

<p attribute="extends test">HTML code with attributes</p> [8, 10]

<!-- HTML Comment --> [11, 12]
```

.

**Comparison**

Compare this to syntax highlighting in Sublime Text using [PHP-Twig.tmbundle](https://github.com/Anomareh/PHP-Twig.tmbundle) by Andrew Fricke or [Craft-Twig.tmbundle](https://github.com/BarrelStrength/Craft-Twig.tmbundle) by Ben Parizek:

[image]

Comment: Nicael [reported this as a bug](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/50/bug-in-syntax-highlighting), but it's obviously an issue.

Comment: Since this was [specifically requested and added earlier](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12/is-there-a-way-to-turn-on-twig-syntax-colors-on-the-beta-site/14#14), I'm going to keep an eye on responses here before immediately reversing the change. I think it makes sense to turn off the default `lang-php` option for the tags that are using it, and encourage people to use `<!-- language: lang-twig -->` in the code block if desired.

Comment: @Matt I was about to add the bugs I found to nicael bug report. But because I found so many of them (and I probably didn't find them all), I decided to open a discussion about removing the highlighting altogether temporarily.

Comment: Official documentation on [buildwithcraft.com](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs) works well for me without any highlighting, way more readable then much of the code over here. I just changed highlighting from `lang-none` to `lang-twig` with [one of my answers](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/882/125), I think this works very good as an example of how bad this actually works so far.

Comment: Hey @Christian, the other mods and I have chatted briefly about this and didn't come to any formal conclusion. But this request has not been forgotten, and has a lot of merit. Let me touch base with them again, and we'll try to get you a conclusive response soon!

Comment: It needs to be fixed, but I think it's better then nothing. I vote we keep it running in the interim before it's updated.

Comment: @Simon no I think it is way worse than nothing. Just look at that example I posted above. Not only not helpfull, it is confusing and irritating especially for twig newcomers!

Comment: What about getting Brandon's new twig highlighting over here, @Lindsey? In his code I trust ;) In the meantime I'd still vote to disable it for now!

Comment: @Lindsey I just found the next bug: "Complete twig syntax highlighting fails if the code begins with html ([see ex. here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1489/125))". Wow, I can't believe that we still need to have this running! Shall we start to bug fix the syntax highlighting by adding unnecessary code to questions or answers...

Comment: @Christian Yikes, that's a serious bug! Definitely not acceptable when about half the examples here are Twig (and many start with HTML). Anna and I are still trying to get to the bottom of the best solution here... It's looking like we're going to disable _all_ automatic syntax highlighting, and just provide some sort of FAQ page which will show people how to manually add their own syntax highlighting. I don't think we can use Brandon's code (or otherwise make custom modifications) because SE is relying on [Google Code Prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109) to work its magic.

Comment: @Lindsey and what about all the code snippets where `<!-- language: lang-twig -->` is already added? They'll still look like cr.. (sorry) or I'll have to open them all up and remove the line?! Please just remove it altogether. It's just for now until s.o. makes it work properly. In the meantime we can all continue to use it in the markup and then, some day,  they'll all look beautiful :D

Comment: @Christian Believe it or not, I don't think Twig syntax is even supported. Which means that every time someone uses that `language` tag, the parser is doing exactly... nothing. Or more specifically, it's falling back to "default" detection, which is generally picking it up as HTML.

Comment: @Christian I can't find a single reference anywhere on the interwebs about Google Code Prettify supporting Twig... If you can find it mentioned somewhere that Twig is supported, please paste a link here and I will continue to investigate. Thanks!

Comment: @Lindsey will do, but isn't that enough of a reason to disable it NOW?

Comment: @Christian There isn't anything to disable. If Twig syntax isn't supported, the parser will treat it as "default"... it attempts to just guess the best match. At this point, the best we can do is force `none` or `html` as the automatic highlighting for anything with a "twig" tag. I'd like to hear more from the community and other mods before we make a decision like that.

Comment: @Lindsey then I misunderstood this: http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/14/125. Damn!

Comment: @Christian Yeah, I think a lot of people got confused by that post (including me). I left a comment over there asking Shog9 for clarification.

Comment: @Lindsey thanks for clearing things up! One last question though. You can set automatic highlighting to `none` (all other options - like `html` - gives us the same code mess again). Additionally could you please investigate if it is possible to make all `lang-twig` tagged code to behave as if it was tagged with `none`? This would be great because we could further use the tag to make our posts "future proof"! :D And you could also tag this Q/A as "status-accepted", even if twig syntax highlighting is a myth, because you solved the actual problem, the highlighting mess we have right now, hehe.

Comment: @carlcs If someone manually specifies their code reference, it's not possible for us to override it... their reference will either match something which exists, or the system will "default" and just try to guess. I'm curious to know if auto-highlighting "twig" tags to `none` is the best move, would love to hear what the community thinks. We should probably start a new Meta thread, posing that question.

Comment: @carlcs Done, now we let the community decide: http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/81/should-any-automatic-syntax-highlighting-be-applied-to-twig-examples

Comment: @Lindsey I didn't mean override but to give the currently unassigned `lang-twig` the same highlighting as `none`. Basically defining it as a duplicate as `none`. Yes, this is probably s.th. you can't do yourself, but maybe you could ask someone of the supermods? Oh and thanks for that new thread, good idea!

Comment: @carlcs Interesting, good idea. I don't know if it's possible, but I'll run it by the supermods. Thanks!

Comment: @Lindsey any news on this? Good to have code in [tag:twig] posts set to `none` as a default now, thanks for this! But I want more, hehe. :D

Answer (score 1):

#### Twig syntax highlighting is apparently a myth.

I did a lot of research, and [wrote about my findings here...](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/twig-syntax-highlighting-is-a-myth)