# Should any automatic syntax highlighting be applied to Twig examples?

Tags: discussion, twig, syntax-highlighting

Since [Twig syntax highlighting is a myth](https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78/twig-syntax-highlighting-is-a-myth), should we have [twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twig) tagged posts adhere to some other auto-highlighting syntax?

The best options would probably be either `html` (which could lead to weird highlighting issues) or `none` (which would just render plain black text).

Any thoughts, feedback, suggestions? (Leave it as an answer, not a comment.)

Answer (score 3):

I think we should color [twig](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twig) posts with `none`. Better to have no highlighting than the opportunity to invite confusion over it.

Comment: Would that override custom set tags (probably not) :(

Comment: @carlcs If by "custom set tags" you mean highlighting specified by the post author via `<!-- language: lang-twig -->`, then no, I don't believe the tag setting would override the post's. But I have no idea what highlighting takes precedence two tags (like [tag:twig] and [tag:forms]) conflict with one another.

Comment: I meant author set tags. Looking for a way to handle all those already `lang-twig` treated posts.

Comment: @carlcs Diligent editing? Good question.

Comment: Ohhh this is probably a job only moderators are authorized to do, right?

Comment: @carlcs That exciting task is anyone's to take on. Moderators need not even do anything! :)

Comment: Alright, so this seemed to be the end of the conversation... I'll change Twig tags to `none` by default, and people can add whatever language coloring they want. Thanks for the feedback!